# Read sms only for OTP

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my android application i am implementing auto fill OTP from SMS, I learnt from this link http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/06/reading-incoming-message-automatically-to-verify-OTP.html

My doubt is `BroadcastReceiver` reads every sms received by the user, can we stop this? I need to read sms at a particular time Example: only after user clicks the send OTP button after that I should stop reading sms.

Please help me how to start and stop the `BroadcastReceiver` for particular period of time.

Comment: Register and unregister your receiver programatically.

Comment: You can register receiver on sen OTP & unregister receiver after getting OTP. Or you can read the SMS of particular number.

Comment: I know that, please provide some example for better understanding. Thank u:)

Comment: you can run a regx on your sms to check if it contains sms otp in it and get it

Comment: Dude anyway i am reading every sms right?? see that link it has if condition to read that otp, thats not my problem i need to stop BroadcastReceiver @SaravInfern

Comment: you can unregister your boardcast receiver after you receive your sms `unregisterReceiver(yourreceiver);
yourreceiver = null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out.

```
private BroadcastReceiver SmsListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // ---get the SMS message
                                                    // passed in---
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                // String msg_from;
                if (bundle != null) {
                    // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
                    try {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage
                                    .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                            // msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                            // do your stuff
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

and as per i did

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    YourActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(SmsListener);
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    YourActivity.this.registerReceiver(SmsListener, i);
}
```

but as others suggested you can register BroadcastReceiver after request for OTP and unregistered after getting OTP.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you , I modified your code as per my usage :)

Answer (score 1):

your can enable and disable the receiver whenever you want. Try the following,

*For Enabling the receiver*

```
public void enableSMSReceiver(Context context){
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, YOUR_RECEIVER.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            component,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

*For Disbling the receiver*

```
public static void disableSMSReceiver(Context context){
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, YOUR_RECEIVER.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        component,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now there are other options to read the OTP SMS automatically, where your app reads only your OTP SMS and this doesn't require any permission grants from the users.

**1. Using SMS Retriever API in Google play services:**

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzWYv8y2v1c

But this requires some server level changes in the OTP SMS format. And this works only in the devices that have Play services installed.

**2. Using createAppSpecificSmsToken in the SmsManager class (from Android O only):**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#createAppSpecificSmsToken(android.app.PendingIntent

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-phone-number-verification-with-sms-token--cms-29141

This works only in Android O, as of now.